# SQL/JPQL 'Between' for numbers represented as strings

Tags: sql, jpql

I have a table where numbers are represented as Strings.

Is there a way to make an SQL/JPQL `between` query function as though they are Integers?

Currently `between 100 and 110` returns 1001, 1002, 1015 etc. It should return only the numbers between 100 and 110.

The column type cannot be changed.

Comment: Why are you storing numbers as strings?

Comment: Not me, I'm just taking a look at it. It is a part of a pretty old product and nobody's sure why it was done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try casting the value column as a numeric datatype before doing the comparison, like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM YOURTABLE
WHERE CAST(VALUE AS INT) BETWEEN 100 AND 110
```

This will ensure that comparison is done on numeric values, not text.

If you are passing parameters of `VARCHAR` data type as parameters, you will also need to explicitly cast them like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM YOURTABLE
WHERE CAST(VALUE AS INT) BETWEEN (CAST @Lower AS INT) AND (CAST @Upper AS INT)
```